# change properties of two divs with one onclick and querySelectorAll()

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, jquery-selectors

I have multiple elements that are seperatet in two divs. The first div contains a Text and the second div a color.
When I click on one element the text and color should change and if I click it again it should change back.
The problem is that no matter which one I click, its always the last one which changes.

The HTML part:

```
<style>
    .colorGreen {
        background-color: green;
    }

    .colorRed {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<div class="box2">Text1</div>
<div class="box1 colorGreen">O</div>
<div class="box2">Text1</div>
<div class="box1 colorGreen">O</div>
<div class="box2">Text1</div>
<div class="box1 colorGreen">O</div>
```

The JavaScript part:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var box1Temp = document.querySelectorAll(".box1");
    var box2Temp = document.querySelectorAll(".box2");
    for (var i = 0; i < box1Temp.length; i++) {
        var box1 = box1Temp[i];
        var box2 = box2Temp[i];
        box2.onclick = box1.onclick = function() {
            if (box1.classList.contains("colorGreen")) {
                box1.classList.add("colorRed");
                box1.classList.remove("colorGreen");
                box2.innerHTML = "Text2";
            } else {
                box1.classList.add("colorGreen");
                box1.classList.remove("colorRed");
                box2.innerHTML = "Text1";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

It works, when I use only one div.
Then I can use 'this', instead of the 'box1' variable, to addres the right element.
But if I replace 'box1' with 'this' its still the text div that changes.
(I know it's obvious that this is happening, but I'm lost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few small tweaks, this can be written a lot more cleanly:

```js
// Capture click event for parent container, .toggle-set
for (const ele of document.querySelectorAll(".toggle-set")) {
    ele.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Grab text and color elements
    const textToggle = ele.querySelector(".toggle-text");    
    const colorToggle = ele.querySelector(".toggle-color");
    
    // Toggle text
    // NOTE: This could use further refinement with regex or something similar to strip whitespace before comparison
    textToggle.textContent = textToggle.textContent == "Text1" ? "Text2" : "Text1";
    
    // Toggle css classes
    colorToggle.classList.toggle("colorGreen");
    colorToggle.classList.toggle("colorRed");
  });
}
```

```css
.colorGreen { background-color: green; }
.colorRed { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="toggle-set">
  <div class="toggle-text">Text1</div>
  <div class="toggle-color colorGreen">
    O
  </div>
</div>

<div class="toggle-set">
  <div class="toggle-text">Text1</div>
  <div class="toggle-color colorGreen">
    O
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is so confused

You were right for the `this` option.

you can do with simple onclick function :

```js
function change(el){
  box1 = el.querySelector('.box1');
  box2 = el.querySelector('.box2');
  if (box1.classList.contains("colorGreen")) {
      box1.classList.add("colorRed");
      box1.classList.remove("colorGreen");
      box2.innerHTML = "Text2";
    } else {
      box1.classList.add("colorGreen");
      box1.classList.remove("colorRed");
      box2.innerHTML = "Text1";
    }
}
```

```html
<style>
    .colorGreen {
        background-color: green;
    }

    .colorRed {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<div onclick="change(this)">
  <div class="box2">Text1</div>
  <div class="box1 colorGreen">O</div>
</div>

<div onclick="change(this)">
  <div class="box2">Text1</div>
<div class="box1 colorGreen">O</div>
  </div>
<div onclick="change(this)">
<div class="box2">Text1</div>
<div class="box1 colorGreen">O</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think following code snippet would help you to get your desired result

```
let box1  = document.querySelectorAll(".box1");
let box2  = document.querySelectorAll(".box2");

box1.forEach((b1,i) => {
  b1.addEventListener("click",(ev) => {
    ev.target.classList.toggle("colorGreen");
    ev.target.classList.toggle("colorRed");
    console.log(box2[i]);
    if(ev.target.classList.contains("colorGreen")){
      box2[i].textContent = "Text1";
    }else{
      box2[i].textContent = "Text2"
    }
  })
})
```